# Como reverter a associação de um arquivo para abrir com outro, no Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Eu peguei uma música copiei e colei no pycharm. A música não era reconhecida, aparecendo a opção Associate with file type, quando cliquei associei o programa a youtrack query , como faço para reverter como estava antes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Menu**
File/Settings/Editor/File Types

> Veja a figura, é intuitivo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]